# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused [Ubuntu 16.04, ES 2.3.4.1, Java 9.0.1]

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, elasticsearch

What error I am getting is. **curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused**

I guess engine stopped working. I had to make engine connection with db mysql using python. I was going all good till the following code.

```
echo '{
"type":"jdbc",
"jdbc":{
"url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ElasticSearchDatabase",
"user":"root",
"password":"",
"sql":"SELECT id as _id, id, name,email FROM test",
"index":"users",
"type":"users",
"autocommit":"true",
"metrics": {
            "enabled" : true
        },
        "elasticsearch" : {
             "cluster" : "servercluster",
             "host" : "localhost",
             "port" : 9300 
        } 
}
}' | java -cp "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.2.0.0/lib/*" -"Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:////etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.2.0.0/bin/log4j2.xml" "org.xbib.tools.Runner" "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"
```

*I got no error in this command but when I did curl localhost:9200 I got connection refused Like after running that code piece, engine stopped working. Please tell me how do I fix.*

Comment: whats error when you run this command `java -cp "/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.2.0.0/lib/*" -"Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:////etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-jdbc-2.2.0.0/bin/log4j2.xml" "org.xbib.tools.Runner" "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"`

Comment: does any elasticsearch service which is running on server ?

Comment: I am new to elasticsearch, There is no error I recieved after running this command.

Comment: NO, no any other service running